# Upload de archivos desde el frontend Svelte y guardado en servidor en SvelteKit JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, imagen, async, upload

Estoy intentando subir un archivo mediante un componente que creo en Svelte, y quiero almacenarlo en el propio servidor, en una carpeta dentro de mi proyecto (a futuro, mediante la API de Google Drive).

Mi backend corre con SvelteKit y, si bien puedo subir la imagen sin problemas, no entiendo como llegar al backend con esta imagen.

```
/* 
    file_name: nombre con el que se guardará el archivo (la extensión se agregará automáticamente)
    file_post: archivo destino para tratar la imagen enviada mediante POST
    save_route: ubicación donde se guardará el archivo
    
 */

document.querySelector('#save-image').addEventListener('click', async function () {
                        let upload = await uploadFile(file_name, avatar);

                        if (upload.error == 0) alert('File uploaded successful');
                        else if (upload.error == 1) alert('Falló la carga - ' + upload.message);
                    });

                    // Manejo asíncrono de la carga
                    async function uploadFile(file_name, avatar) {
                        
                        let return_data = { error: 0, message: '' };

                        try {
                            // no se eligió archivo
                            if (document.querySelector('#file-to-upload').files.length == 0) {
                                throw new Error('No se seleccionó ningún archivo');
                            } else {
                                // formdata
                                let form_data = new FormData();
                                form_data.append(file_name, avatar);
                                form_data.append('Save route', save_route);
                                
                                /* form_data.append('file', document.querySelector('#file-to-upload').files[0]);
 */
                                let response = await fetch('file_post', {
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                                    body: data
                                });

                                if (response.status != 200) throw new Error('HTTP response code != 200');

                                
                                let json_response = await response.json();
                                if (json_response.error == 1) throw new Error(json_response.message);
                            }
                        } catch (e) {
                            return_data = { error: 1, message: e.message };
                        }

                        return return_data;
                    }
                    document.getElementById('info_upload').innerHTML = 'El archivo fue subido con éxito.';
                }
            };
```

¿Cómo tengo que hacer para llegar a tratarlo? Todo parece funcionar bien según lo que veo en consola, pero no tengo respuesta desde mi archivo fileSave.js.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, disculpa tengo una duda ¿A qué te refieres con "como llegar al backend con esta imagen"?

Comment: Hola Jonatan, gracias por tu ayuda. Como decía, quiero guardar el archivo que el usuario suba mediante esta sección:
<input
  id="file-to-upload"
  style="display:none"
  type="file"
  accept={accepted_file_ext}
  on:change={(e) => onFileSelected(e)}
  bind:this={fileInput}
 />

Una vez que el usuario la sube, quiero almacenarla en una carpeta en el servidor. Para poder almacenarla en el servidor, no puedo trabajar del lado del cliente, y eso es precisamente lo que me falta comprender: cómo le doy "guardar"? Dónde va el archivo que lo hace? Cómo lo llamo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema va más del lado del servidor, no tiene que ver mucho con Svelte. Si tienes un formulario con Svelte para subir una imagen, tendrás un :

```
<input id="file-to-upload" type="file" bind:files>

<button on:click={uploadFile}>Submit</button>
```

Aquí debes saber que la variable `files` contendrá el archivo que se seleccione. Ya que estás haciendo un binding.

Posterior a eso, en tu método `uploadFile()`:

```
let files;

function uploadFile() {
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Parámetros que recibe tu endpoint en tu Backend
    formData.append('fileName', files[0].name);
    formData.append('dataFile', files[0]);
    const upload = fetch('file_post', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then((response) => response.json()).then((result) => {
        console.log('El archivo fue subido con éxito');
    })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });

}
```

Con eso sería más que suficiente para trabajarlo desde el frontEnd, luego en tu backEnd (imagino que usas NodeJS), debes tener la lógica para guardar el archivo. Te recomiendo usar [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), si es que aún no has definido la lógica del backend.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Joanatan. En sí, tenés mucha razón en todo, lo único que me falta es saber como llegar al backend. En teoría, lo que propones es lo mismo que vengo haciendo. Mi selección para backend es, precisamente, Sveltekit, un framework desarrollado para trabajar mejor con Svelte en el front. Mi problema es que mi endpoint, lo coloque donde lo coloque, no recibe ningún tipo de información desde el front. He probado enviarlo como imagen o como blob, pero nada, mi endpoint no reacciona en absoluto. De todas maneras, muchas gracias por la respuesta, es muy útil y se agradece.

Comment: @FGarcia Seguramente la imagen es enviada, para recibirlo desde tu BackEnd puedes revisar sobre `formData` en la [documentación](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#hooks-handle) para recibir un response con `multipart/form-data`